# Installing Ioncube on CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ioncube

I am trying to install Ioncube on one of my VPSs.Just a little background. This is a CentOS latest, running on an ESXi latest host. The machine has 2GB memory.

I ran php-based loader wizard. I'm trying to install v5.3.

When re-opening the loader, I am presented with this:

```
Loader Installed
The ionCube Loader version 4.5.3 for PHP 5.3 is already installed and encoded files should run without problems.
```

Some more information for debugging:

```
cat /etc/php.d/20-ioncube.ini
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so


php -v
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: undefined symbol: php_body_write
PHP 5.4.25 (cli) (built: Feb 10 2014 08:04:23)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies

ls -lah /usr/lib64/php/modules/
total 19M
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4.0K Mar 12 17:43 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root  4.0K Mar 11 18:57 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   68K Feb 10 08:07 curl.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2.6M Feb 10 08:07 fileinfo.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  326K Feb 11 08:07 ioncube_loader_lin_4.1.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  324K Feb 11 08:07 ioncube_loader_lin_4.2.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  326K Feb 11 08:07 ioncube_loader_lin_4.3.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  342K Feb 11 08:07 ioncube_loader_lin_4.3_ts.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  328K Feb 11 08:07 ioncube_loader_lin_4.4.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  346K Feb 11 08:07 ioncube_loader_lin_4.4_ts.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  335K Feb 11 08:07 ioncube_loader_lin_5.0.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  347K Feb 11 08:08 ioncube_loader_lin_5.0_ts.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1.1M Feb 11 08:08 ioncube_loader_lin_5.1.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  991K Feb 11 08:08 ioncube_loader_lin_5.1_ts.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1.1M Feb 11 08:08 ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1.1M Feb 11 08:09 ioncube_loader_lin_5.2_ts.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1018K Feb 11 08:09 ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1.1M Feb 11 08:09 ioncube_loader_lin_5.3_ts.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1.2M Feb 11 08:09 ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1.2M Feb 11 08:10 ioncube_loader_lin_5.4_ts.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1.2M Feb 11 08:10 ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1.2M Feb 11 08:10 ioncube_loader_lin_5.5_ts.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   41K Feb 10 08:07 json.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1.3M Feb 10 08:07 mbstring.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  137K Feb 10 08:07 mysqli.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   53K Feb 10 08:07 mysql.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   33K Feb 10 08:07 pdo_mysql.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  100K Feb 10 08:07 pdo.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   26K Feb 10 08:07 pdo_sqlite.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  259K Feb 10 08:07 phar.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   45K Feb 10 08:07 sqlite3.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1.1M Jun 14  2013 ZendGuardLoader.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   93K Feb 10 08:07 zip.so
```

Please advise if you need any additional information. Thank you.

Comment: You're loading ioncube for 5.3 and you're running 5.4. Edit the .ini to point to the right one.

Comment: Thank you! Can you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you're loading ioncube for PHP 5.3, and you're using PHP 5.4.

Adjust the ini file to use 5.4 and you'll be good to go.